# Passing array value using CSV or inline array

Tags: c++, arrays, unions

I have `data` variable in which I am getting 44 array values from `features` from other function..

I want to manually pass these values to `data` variable.

```
  double features[44];
  get_features(ecg_series,csv_data.at(0).size(),features);
  union Entry data[44];
    float result[4];
    char filename[100];
    char res[4]={'A','N','O','~'};
    int index;
  for(int i=0;i<44;i++)
  {
    data[i].missing=-1;
    data[i].fvalue=features[i];
      // printf("feature[%d]=%.8f\n",i,features[i]);
  }
```

This is my code.

I want to do

1. Passing array value to `data` variable directly. This array has 44 double values in it.
2. Or read above 44 values from csv or other file.

How can I do it?

I am not proficient with C++ so could not get understand about how to do this.

Comment: Arrays don't provide such assignment operators. A `std::vector` would provide `assign` function accepting two iterators. If that's an alternative...

Comment: What do you mean by *'OR'*? Wouldn't you need to read the values from CSV anyway, with or without assignment?

Comment: I have two option to get data content. 1. Manually assign values 2. Read from csv files 
I am fine with anyone of this solution

Comment: If data does *not* come from CSV file – where should it come from elsewhere then??? Point is: CSV file involves file reading and parsing, which is a pretty complex process. So if you are fine with just copying *any* data, I don't expect *anyone* to provide another solution than just copy some some statically allocated array with static data into your struct...

Comment: At *\*.cpp*-file level: `namespace { Entry g_initData[44] = { /* some appropriate initializer data */ }; void initialize() { Entry data[sizeof(g_initData)/sizeof(*g_initData)]; memcpy(data, g_initData, sizeof(data)); }` – side note: you don't need to repeat the `union` keyword...

Comment: Be aware that `memcpy`ing arbitrary data can easily lead to undefined behaviour if your union members contain anything else than POD objects; if that's the case you should rather switch to `std::variant` and `std::copy` (well, actually you should anyway...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: Thanks really appreciate, I tried somethign like this but there eI have `NaN` value problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72172633/how-to-assign-nan-value-in-double-array

Comment: That question is solved isn't it? `#include <limits> double g_features[] = { 0.0, 0.1, std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(), };` – I recommend preferring the C++ facility over the C facility as the former is a  `constexpr` function, i.e. no runtime overhead.